# Reusable Custom Styled TextField with CSS classes in MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make this component reusable, but whenever I wrap this component into a wrapped component I am getting an error.
I am deliberately try to use scss classes and not to use styled-components.

Here is the non-reusable component:

```
      <InputField
        id="<id_name>"
        label="<label>"
        variant="outlined"
        inputRef={inputRef}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
          setValue(e.target.value)
        }}
        InputProps={{
          classes: {
            root: styles.search__field,  // this is standart modular scss class
            notchedOutline: styles.search__field, // this is standart modular scss class
          },
        }}
        InputLabelProps={{
          classes: {
            shrink: styles.search__label__focused, // this is standart modular scss class
          },
        }}
      />
```

I tried to write an reusable component like this:

```
import { TextField, type TextFieldProps } from "@mui/material"

type InputFieldProps = {
  rootClass: string
  borderClass: string
  shrinkLabelClass: string
} & TextFieldProps

const InputField = ({
  rootClass,
  borderClass,
  shrinkLabelClass,
  InputProps,
  InputLabelProps,
  ...restProps
}: InputFieldProps) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      {...restProps}
      InputProps={{
        classes: {
          root: rootClass,
          notchedOutline: borderClass,
        },
      }}
      InputLabelProps={{
        classes: {
          shrink: shrinkLabelClass,
        },
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

but I am getting that error:

> The TextField is a convenience wrapper for the most common cases (80%). It cannot be all things to all people, otherwise the API would grow out of control.
>
> Type '{ InputProps: { classes: { root: string; notchedOutline: string; }; }; InputLabelProps: { classes: { shrink: string; }; }; onChange?: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement> | undefined; ... 284 more ...; onTransitionEndCapture?: TransitionEventHandler<...> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TextFieldProps'.
> The types of 'InputProps.classes' are incompatible between these types.
> Type '{ root: string; notchedOutline: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial'.
> Property 'notchedOutline' does not exist on type 'Partial'.ts(2322)

I also tried to change the rootClass, borderClass, shrinkLabelClass type string to Partial but that time I am getting error from "root" property saying that needs to be a string type.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to add props (`notchedOutline`) that only applies to outlined variant of `TextField`. So you can add wrapper like this for the outlined variant

```
type InputFieldProps = {
    rootClass: string
    borderClass: string
    shrinkLabelClass: string
} & OutlinedTextFieldProps

const OutlinedInputField = ({
    rootClass,
    borderClass,
    shrinkLabelClass,
    InputProps,
    InputLabelProps,
    ...restProps
}: InputFieldProps) => {
    return (
        <TextField
            {...restProps}
            InputProps={{
                classes: {
                    root: rootClass,
                    notchedOutline: borderClass,
                },
            }}
            InputLabelProps={{
                classes: {
                    shrink: shrinkLabelClass,
                },
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: It is perfectly done.! Thank you so much! But I still do not understand why (TextFieldProps) did not work. When I look at its source it also contains the OutlineTextFieldProps "export type TextFieldProps = StandardTextFieldProps | FilledTextFieldProps | OutlinedTextFieldProps;"

Comment: because you are using `notchedOutline` which only exists in `OutlinedTextFieldProps` - so if you someone wants other variant - the props does not exist